# Phonegap iOS Plugin for UITextView?

Tags: ios, cordova, uitextview

I am trying to find a Text view / editor for Phonegap iOS Application.

Basically I am expecting it to be looking like

[image]

with a custom header. So my question is that can I just inherit the UITextView portion from the plugin if there is any and still use my customized header of my HTML?

This is a Notes app that I am creating to make which requires this. I tried using regular jQuery, Html, CSS for this but it starts jumping all over  when I enter text.